# simulating data from regression line in python

Tags: python, numpy, regression

If I have a regression line and an r squared is there a simple numpy (or some other library) command to randomly draw, say, y values for an x that are consistent with the regression? The same way you could just draw a random value from a distribution?

Thanks!

Comment: This *might* be a better fit for http://stats.stackexchange.com/ (not sure, so am not voting to close.)

Comment: He's asking for a `numpy` command - I think it belongs here

Comment: well I posted it over there and they moved it back here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to go would be to get the parameter values from the regression and use an appropriate distribution from either [`numpy`](http://www.scipy.org/doc/api_docs/SciPy.stats.distributions.html) or [`scipy`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html).